# Apple Pay Web Merchant Registration API

Tags: applepay

just want to clarify regarding the apple pay register merchant API. Here is the sample payload from the apple pay docs:

```
{ 
  "domainNames": ["domain-name"], 
  "encryptTo": "merchant-id", 
  "partnerInternalMerchantIdentifier": "partner-merchant-id", 
  "partnerMerchantName": "merchant-name" 
}
```

Should the partnerInternalMerchantIdentifier needs be an apple merchantIdentifier or it can be any unique string identifier of the merchant we are registering?

Your inputs will be a big help. Thanks!